# Update first row with oldest, the next with second oldest, and so forth

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, auto-increment

I'm having trouble writing an update in SQL Server with no relations. I have looked all over the forum but I have a hard time to find the answer.

I need to update the OCR from if the Customer, Amount is matching. The problem is that this is not a unique key. So, if there is more then one record from the customer, amount combination, I need to take the oldest match in the lookup table and update the OCR from it. Then I need to take the second oldest and update the second row with its OCR.

I tried to visualize it in the tables below.

All suggestions are welcome!

**Table to update - before update**

```
Customer       OCR  Amount      
740000010417        220.000     
740000010417        220.000     
740000010421        300.000     
740000010421        250.000
```

**Lookup Table**

```
Customer         OCR            Amount  Date                    ID
740000010417    222357110626    220.000 2011-11-11 15:48:48.510 100642
740000010417    222350553822    220.000 2011-10-18 10:10:26.210 18680
740000010417    222350464525    220.000 2011-10-18 10:10:26.210 18681
740000010417    222357110725    220.000 2011-11-11 15:48:48.510 102547
740000010421    222357127726    250.000 2011-11-11 15:48:48.510 102548
740000010421    222357127725    220.000 2011-10-19 10:10:26.210 102549
740000010421    222357130555    250.000 2011-10-19 10:10:26.210 102550
```

**Table after update**

```
Customer            OCR          Amount     
740000010417    222350553822    220.000     
740000010417    222350464525    220.000     
740000010421                    300.000     
740000010421    222357130555    250.000
```

Comment: Not sure you can do that without resorting to some form of cursor, but I'll be happy to see a solution without one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set ocr = 

(select l.ocr
from 
(select l.customer as customer, l.ocr as ocr, l.amount as amount, l.date as date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by l.customer, l.amount Order BY l.date) as RowNum
from lookuptable l
order by l.date
)a

(select t.customer as customer, t.amount as amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.customer, t.amount order by t.customer) as RowNum
from table t
)b
where a.customer = b.customer and a.amount=b.amount and a. rowNum = b.RowNum
)
```

I have not tested it, but its might give you an idea.

Edit:
just realized no need to join in inner query.
Idea is to first select all the records from look up table and assign them row number in ascending order of date. 
so same customer and same amount with different dates will get row numbers in increment orders.

Then get records from old table and assign row numbers to them partiioned by customer and amount. This way we can match customer, amount and row number sunch that first same customer and amount will be initialized oldest OCR, as rows are ordered by date

Comment: Hi, haven't tested it yet but but it looks very promesing. Your edit note was very informative and I think I will figure it out/apply it to my script. Thanks! One other thing, I hade a quick glance att the theread over my phone a day ago. Then there was a script from an other guy also. But now it is gone, don't know where it has gone. I will try the query in an hour or so. Will let you know. sia

Comment: What happend to te second answer? Wo deleted it? Is it possibele to restore? There were some interesting code there?

Comment: @user641605 I have no idea, But I guess only owner can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with that worked like a charm! Thanks Zohaib!

```
UPDATE   t1
SET    t1.ocr = l1.ocr    
FROM    ( SELECT    *
              , rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.customer,
                                          t.Amount ORDER BY t.customer, t.Amount )
           FROM      table t) t1
        LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT    *
              , rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY l.customer,
                                          l.Amount ORDER BY l.date, l.id)
          FROM      lookuptable l) l1

      ON t1.id = l1.id
        AND t1.Amount = l1.amount
        AND t1.rnk = l1.rnk
```